# Understanding Shankar's standard deviation: Is $\langle\psi|\Omega|\psi\rangle$ shorthand for $\langle\psi|\Omega|\psi\rangle I$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, notation, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

On page 128 of Shankar's book, he defines the standard deviation as follows:
$$\Delta\Omega=[\langle\psi|(\Omega-\langle\psi|\Omega|\psi\rangle)^2|\psi\rangle]^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
Now, this equation is undefined as is, because $\langle\psi|\Omega|\psi\rangle$ is a scalar and $\Omega$ is an operator. Is $\langle\psi|\Omega|\psi\rangle$ shorthand for $\langle\psi|\Omega|\psi\rangle I$, or is it something different?

Comment: Why do you think scalar multiplication isn’t one kind of operation on a vector? What is $V(\vec{r})$ in the Schrodinger equation?

Comment: "Is $\langle\psi|\Omega|\psi\rangle$ shorthand for $\langle\psi|\Omega|\psi\rangle I$[...]" Yes.

Comment: I say no. To multiply a scalar times a vector, there is no need to insert a pointless identity operator. One of the axioms of a vector space is that scalar multiplication is allowed.

Comment: @G.Smith That's right, but $\langle\psi|\Omega|\psi\rangle$ is a scalar and $\Omega$ is an operator, so OP wants to know how those two are being subtracted.

Comment: Scalars can act as operators. They do not need an identity operator to help them. So I consider that the subtraction of one operator from another. I don’t think this is an eccentric point of view, but we’ll see what others say.

Comment: @G.Smith  For example, if you represented the operators as matrices, then it doesn't make sense to subtract a single number from a matrix. Even with your $V(\mathbf r)$ example, that is a function of an operator that is itself an operator (matrix). It isn't a single number like an expectation value is. Technically the identity operator needs to be there, although I do agree that it doesn't necessarily need to be written if you understand what is going on.

Comment: In the case of matrices, I agree that it must be there either implicitly or explicitly. But quantum mechanics does not have to be done with matrices.

Comment: @G.Smith Yes of course, but you should always be able to think in that way. I think you are getting around it by thinking more in terms of using a distributive property. I think it's not a huge deal overall. And also, if you want specific people to see your comments you should tag them in the comment.

Comment: This argument is entirely about notation. Everyone here is agreeing that a scalar is not an operator, but scalar multiplication *is* an operator. The only disagreement is whether the notation in the OP makes it sufficiently obvious that the appearance of the scalar actually denotes the scalar multiplication operator. I think that the very existence of this question demonstrates that (to at least one person) that fact is not obvious, so in a first course in QM it may be worth inserting the identity operator explicitly, just to show that the scalar actually denotes scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if you want to explicitly combine $(\Omega-\langle\psi|\Omega|\psi\rangle)^2$ into a single operator without actually using it on a state, then you would need to put the identity operator in for the math to make sense.

However, as pointed out in the comments, multiplying a state by a scalar is a perfectly valid operation. Therefore, you could easily apply the distributive law for the operator/scalar terms and then be perfectly fine with not even thinking about the identity operator. i.e.

$$\langle(\Omega-\langle\Omega\rangle)^2\rangle=\langle \Omega^2\rangle+\langle\langle\Omega\rangle^2\rangle-2\langle\langle\Omega\rangle\Omega\rangle=\langle \Omega^2\rangle-\langle\Omega\rangle^2$$
where I have condensed the notation to avoid clutter of $|\psi\rangle$ terms.

In my opinion, there is nothing wrong with putting in the identity operator, so if that is what makes the most sense to you then go ahead and think of it like that.