# Commutation of the operators used in definition of dispersion in Sakurai's proof of uncertainity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, notation, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Given a Hermitian operator $A$, Sakurai (in his book "Modern Quantum Mechanics") defines $\Delta A$ as follows:
$$\Delta A = A - \langle A\rangle$$
Where I believe $\langle A\rangle\vert\psi\rangle = \langle A\rangle_\psi\vert\psi\rangle$ is the definition of the operator.
He then goes on to define dispersion as
$$\langle (\Delta A)^2\rangle=\langle( A^2-2A\langle A\rangle + \langle A \rangle^2)\rangle=\langle A^2\rangle - \langle A\rangle^2$$
I am stuck here, shouldn't
$$(\Delta A)^2=A^2-A\langle A\rangle - \langle A\rangle A + \langle A \rangle^2$$
Since according to my calculation the operators don't commute:
$$A(\langle A\rangle\vert\psi\rangle)= \langle A\rangle_\psi A\vert\psi\rangle$$
$$\langle A \rangle (A\vert\psi\rangle) = \left[(\langle\psi\vert A^\dagger)A(A\vert\psi\rangle)\right]A\vert\psi\rangle =(\langle\psi\vert A^3\vert\psi\rangle)A\vert\psi\rangle$$

**Edit:** With the way $\langle A \rangle$ is defined, it's not even a linear operator. How then is it used to make a valid quantum mechanical operator?

Comment: $\langle A \rangle$ is a number

Comment: $\langle A \rangle := \langle \psi |A |\psi \rangle$.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too. But Sakurai uses it to define an operator. And this is the only way I could make sense of it.

Comment: I've used $\langle A\rangle_\psi = \langle \psi\vert A \vert \psi\rangle$

Comment: There is an implicit identity operator missing, i.e. $\Delta A_\psi:=A- \langle \psi, A\psi\rangle I$ would be a better notation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Shankar's standard deviation: Is $\langle\psi|\Omega|\psi\rangle$ shorthand for $\langle\psi|\Omega|\psi\rangle I$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/492610/)